# Common .NET interface for a custom "ToString()" implementation provider?

Tags: .net, interface, string-formatting

I wrote a helper method for some unit tests to assert "collection equivalence" using a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementation:

```
/// <summary>
/// Known issue: this checks for set-equality, which means that duplicate items will be interpreted as one.
/// </summary>
public static void AssertCollectionsAreEquivalent<T>(ICollection<T> expected, ICollection<T> actual,
        IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
{
    T[] commonMembers = expected.Intersect(actual, comparer).ToArray();
    T[] missingMembers = expected.Except(actual, comparer).ToArray();
    T[] extraMembers = actual.Except(expected, comparer).ToArray();
    if (missingMembers.Any() || extraMembers.Any())
    {
        Assert.Fail("Collections were not equivalent.{0}Common members: {1}{0}Missing members: {2}{0}Extra members: {3}",
            Environment.NewLine,
            string.Join(", ", commonMembers.Select(t => t.ToString())),
            string.Join(", ", missingMembers.Select(t => t.ToString())),
            string.Join(", ", extraMembers.Select(t => t.ToString())));
    }
}
```

Along the way, it seemed helpful to allow the caller to provide an object that could provide custom string formatting, but I didn't see an interface in .NET that fit the bill.  I ended up using a `Func<T, string>` for now:

```
/// <summary>
/// Known issue: this checks for set-equality, which means that duplicate items will be interpreted as one.
/// </summary>
private static void AssertCollectionsAreEquivalent<T>(ICollection<T> expected, ICollection<T> actual,
    IEqualityComparer<T> comparer, Func<T, string> toStringConverter)
{
    T[] commonMembers = expected.Intersect(actual, comparer).ToArray();
    T[] missingMembers = expected.Except(actual, comparer).ToArray();
    T[] extraMembers = actual.Except(expected, comparer).ToArray();
    if (missingMembers.Any() || extraMembers.Any())
    {
        Assert.Fail("Collections were not equivalent.{0}Common members: {1}{0}Missing members: {2}{0}Extra members: {3}",
            Environment.NewLine,
            string.Join(", ", commonMembers.Select(toStringConverter)),
            string.Join(", ", missingMembers.Select(toStringConverter)),
            string.Join(", ", extraMembers.Select(toStringConverter)));
    }
}
```

The motivation for this is a unit test suite that uses a common test DTO for retrieving items from a data store, but we have different definitions of equality for different test scenarios (hence the `IEqualityComparer<T>` argument).  I know that I could define a custom interface to do what I want:

```
public interface IToStringProvider<in T>
{
    string ToString(T obj);
}
```

... but I was hoping that there might be some existing item that would fit the bill.

Comment: Have you heard of [`Enumerable.SequenceEquals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348567%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, but that checks for sequence-equality (same items, same order), and I really just want collection-equality (same items, any order).  I know that my example implements set-equality; I'll update it in the future so that duplicate items are handled correctly.

Comment: Unsure why someone would downvote this. Seems well worded, code examples, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Look at [`IFormattable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It may do what you want, though not in quite the same way. You may need to add a type constraint on that method, but you'll find that quite a few types already implement this.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, but if I'm understanding you correctly, it would require the DTO to implement IFormattable, and I want to be able to provide different string representations of the DTO based on different definitions of equality.  Maybe this indicates that a common DTO isn't the best approach for this problem...